# File with * * * * cron format

Tags: cron

I know that:
`cron Minute Hour Day_of_the_Month Month_of_the_Year Day_of_the_Week`.
I found out that one of my files has cron set to `* * * *`. 
Will file with cron set to `* * * *` will be ever called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format for crontab files would require that that be five *'s. So either you're missing a start or missing a number (or more complex expression like 1,3,5). If the line is:

```
* * * * * do something
```

It will get run every minute.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a file set to * * * * means the event to run every minute .